# $L^1- L^\infty$ estimate for the semi group of wave equations

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

I am looking for a proof of the following lemma
[image]

for the case where:

- $y= (y_1,\cdots, y_n)\mapsto  P(y) = \|y\|_2= \sqrt{y_1^2+ \cdots + y_n^2}.$
  In this case the rank of the mentioned matrix is $n-1$ for $y\neq 0$
- ${\rm supp}(v)= \{y \in \mathbb{R}^n , 1<\|y\|_2 <2 \}$

The author referred to the following [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-69/issue-6/Fourier-transforms-of-surface-carried-measures-and-differentiability-of-surface/bams/1183525687.full) for the proof in the general case as stated above where It was done in the frame of Fourier transform of surface carried measures and its behaviour at the infinity. I wonder if there is another (more direct) proof which uses the usual techniques of functional analysis ($L^p$ estimates, interpolation estimates ...etc.)

Thank you for any hint.
EDIT:

Here is what I found in the literature for the general proof:
In the following paper (see picture below): the Lemma 2.1 seems to have a result of the same nature
[image]

where the author referred again the this [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-69/issue-6/Fourier-transforms-of-surface-carried-measures-and-differentiability-of-surface/bams/1183525687.full) from which I took a screenshot of the main result
[image]

I wonder what the role of the assumption on the Hessian and the parameter $t$ is.

Comment: Do you understand in your second source, Proof of Lemma 2.1, it says you can assume that $\phi\in {\mathcal D}({\mathbb R}^m)$ can be taken as a finite sum each supported on a sphere? I understand quite a bit of the other parts, except this one.

Comment: I am trying to communicate what I begin to understand. I think the paper of Littman requires the principal curvatures of the surface $S$ to be nonzero. If you make the surface the level surface of your $P$, then the number of nonzero principal curvatures is the same as the rank of the Hessian matrix of $P$. I think that is the main relation.

Comment: This is still a mystery  for me. I want to understand how the author in the OP used the result of Littman and where the term $(1+|t|)^{-\rho/2 }$ came from.